# how to debug when sql server timesout using a stored procedure at a certain time of day

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net (version 4) and am trying to run a stored procedure which I have created

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[some_proc]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[some_proc](Creation_Date)
    VALUES (getDate());

    select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

The procedure runs fine when called from within server management studio (runs in less than a second) and also runs fine from my web app UNTIL the afternoon (about 3pm), at which point I get a timeout error, as below:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:29.9969982. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Other stored procedures that I try and run and return expected results. All the stored procedures query the same database.

I have reviewed several other answers on similar questions but they haven't helped me regarding this situation.

I realise this issue may be very specific to my situation, and if it is then my question would be how do I start to debug this issue (any tools or techniques would be really helpful)

Comment: are you trying to insert into a stored procedure? `INSERT INTO [dbo].[some_proc](Creation_Date)`

Comment: Did you change that proc at all?  Your table name matches your proc name -- that can't be right.

Comment: Note that the error is not a SQL timout but a WCF timeout.  Is there also a WCF service call involved?

Comment: @Dan Guzman I was using a service, but I was having so many issues I stopped (just trying to rule out all possible issues).

Answer (score 1):

You could run a SQL Server Profiler session recording database activity between 2.30 and 3.30

also check SQL Server Agent for any jobs that start around that time